# Compare column values in mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, inner-join

I have two tables, table A and table B. I need to compare their columns to get values of one table that are not in other table.

- Table A columns : ID,table_id(key reference to table B),data
- Table B columns : ID(primary key,references to table A),x,y

I need to get values from A.table_id that are not equal to B.ID

A.table_id values = 3,3,2
B.ID values = 1,2,3

I need to get value 1.

Comment: You can use `not in`, `not exists`, or a `left join`.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple, you have to start reading basic of SQL. **[MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826(v=sql.90).aspx)**

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA 
WHERE table_id NOT IN (SELECT id from tableB)
```